# How to pass parameters to Extjs application during its launch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I am creating a project in extjs using Sencha Architect. It consists of a login application (login.js) which checks for successful login and gets the user's roles and redirects to another application (main.js). I want to pass username and role information into main.js to be accessed by various components for rendering. I am not able to pass these parameters from one application to another, please suggest the right way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: You can use HttpSession.Set the user info to session attribute,and you can access it in your index.jsp by requesting the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On successfull login and setting the session attribute with the
>   appropriate login info,you are redirecting to **some.jsp** which is
>   starting point of **main.js**

In **some.jsp**

```
<body>
<%
    String userId = (String)session.getAttribute("userID");
 %>
 <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="<%=userId%>"/>
</body>
```

So on you can get the login info on loading the viewport of main.js as :

```
var username = Ext.get("userID").getValue();
```

> You can then use username throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

How about **some.jsp**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var username = '<%=session.getAttribute("userID")%>';
</script>
```